# mySQL select - how to retrieve only 1 result and the highest number ID?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a PHP script that retrieves messages from a database and then displays them in an inbox style way, one line for each message. Each message is part of a conversation between 2 users. Right now, the problem is that it returns 1 new message in the output for every message in the conversation.

If that makes sense? Here is the code for the query:

```
 $sql_select_messages = $db->query( ... );
```

Where the argument is the following query string:

```
SELECT m.admin_message, a.name, u.username AS sender_username, 
    m.* FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "messaging m
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "items a ON a.items_id=m.items_id
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "users u ON u.user_id=m.sender_id
WHERE m.receiver_id='" . $session->value('user_id') . "' AND m.receiver_deleted=0" .
    (($page == 'summary') ? " AND m.is_read=0" : '') . "
ORDER BY " . $order_field . " " . $order_type . " LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $limit
```

The part of:

```
m.* FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "messaging m
```

selects the data from mySQL rows that contains columns like

```
topic_id
```

and

```
message_id
```

What I'm trying to do is have the above mySQL query returns only return ONE (1) result per topic_id (as there may be several topic_id with the same number) and combined with that only the LATEST (highest number) of the message_id.

So basically if there is:

```
================
topic_id | message_id
================
15         10
15         11
15         12
19         02
19         03
19         04
```

I would only want mySQL to return 15/12 and 19/04. How would I go about doing that with the above mySQL select query?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: You have w.name and a r.name, yet I don't see w or r tables here. Think is better you post bare SQL query example here.

Comment: Sorry, I removed that part and forgot it above. Just updated it. Should be correct now :)

Comment: Are both `topic_id` and `message_id` in the same table, or are they in separate tables involved in a JOIN?

Comment: the topic_id and message_id are in the same 'messaging' table.

Comment: Either use a `NOT EXISTS` subquery, or `LEFT JOIN messaging m2` again, on topic id and having a bigger message_id, add  where clause where `m2.topcid_id IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order by two columns, and also group those columns.

Append following scripts to your SQL.

```
GROUP BY topic_id
ORDER BY topic_id DESC, message_id DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the record, I also tried m.topic_id and m.message_id with the same undeclared variable error.

Comment: It does not sounds like a MySQL error. Does it? Did you put the scripts between your quotes? Undeclared variable it looks like you put it outside your SQL script, your compiler take it as variables which the compiler cannot find in your code. MySQL normally should pop out an error like "Unknown column".

Answer (score 0):

Your query might look like this

```sql
SELECT m.admin_message, a.name, u.username sender_username, m.*
  FROM 
(
  SELECT MAX(message_id) message_id
    FROM messaging 
   WHERE ... -- < all your where conditions go here
   GROUP BY topic_id
) q JOIN messaging m ON q.message_id = m.message_id LEFT JOIN items a 
   ON a.items_id = m.items_id LEFT JOIN users u 
   ON u.user_id  = m.sender_id
 ORDER BY ... 
 LIMIT ...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4ec4d/1)** demo

Now on php side it will look like

```php
$sql = "SELECT m.admin_message, a.name, u.username sender_username, m.*
   FROM 
 (
   SELECT MAX(message_id)
     FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "messaging 
    WHERE m.receiver_id = '" . $session->value('user_id') . "' AND m.receiver_deleted = 0 " .
    (($page == 'summary') ? " AND m.is_read = 0" : '') . "
    GROUP BY topic_id
 ) q JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "messaging m ON q.message_id = m.message_id LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "items a 
    ON a.items_id = m.items_id LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "users u 
    ON u.user_id  = m.sender_id
  ORDER BY " . $order_field . " " . $order_type . " LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $limit;
$sql_select_messages = $db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
SELECT topic_id, MAX(message_id)
FROM test
GROUP BY topic_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/271de/2/0